# Prevent SQL injection by rejecting English characters?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection, detect

I try to create a comment session on a web site in which the users will be non-English speakers and as a results their comments will be in their mother tongue.
If I use the following code which I found here ( [PHP Detect if non-english ), it means that I will prevent the SQL injections?

```
$string = $_POST['comment'];
if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
{ 
    echo "proceed";
    require_once('db_file.php');
}
else {
    echo "English Detected.";
    exit();
}
```

I tested it and if I use English characters mixed with Chinese/Greek/Polish, it turns out that it 'exits' the code.
Any idea/opinion about that? Of course, I will put the "mysqli_real_escape_string" but I would like to know if the English detection provides me with additional security.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: No; it just provides you with extra annoyance.

Comment: I appreciate the creativity, but this is the worst ever approach to the problem. Also, if a Chinese person writes "Apple" as in "Apple iPhone", the comment won't get through. I think implementing this would probably be a good explanation of the English term "shooting himself in the foot".

Answer (score 3):

Does it provide additional security? **No**.

The proper escaping function (`mysql_real_escpae_string` in this case) is exactly what you need, nothing more nothing less.